# jQuery Character Count not working inside phtml foreach loop

Tags: jquery, foreach, php

I'm having trouble getting a character count to work inside a foreach loop - please see below in my phtml file.

The character count works outside of the div data-bind="foreach: task" loop, but when I include the loop, it loads - but doesn't run from that point on.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span18">
        <h2 class="PIMS3">Task Details</h2>
        <div id="taskList">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1">Dept</div>
                <div class="span1">Skill</div>
                <div class="span3">Description</div>
                <div class="span3">Notes</div>
                <div class="span6">Budget</div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#textAreaDescriptions").keyup(function() {
                            var CharacterNo1 = $(this).val().length;
                            $("#CharacterCount1").html ("Characters Used:50 : " + CharacterNo1);
                        });
                    });

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#textAreaNote').keyup(function () {
                            var CharacterNo2 = $(this).val().length;
                            $('#CharacterCount2').html("Characters Used:150 : " + CharacterNo2);
                        });
                 })(jQuery);
            </script>

            <div data-bind="foreach: tasks">

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="span1"><select class="span1" data-bind="options: $parent.departmentList, value: department"></select></div>

                     <div class="span1"><select class="span1" data-bind="options: skillList, value: skill"></select></div>

                     <div class="span3"><input class="span3" name = "description" id="textAreaDescriptions"  data-bind="value: description"  placeholder="Max Character Limit 50" maxlength="50" >
                         <div id="CharacterCount1" style="padding: 4px; float: left; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">Character Count:50:0</div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="span3"><input class="span3" name = "notes" id="textAreaNote"  data-bind="value: notes" placeholder="Max Character Limit 150" maxlength= "150">
                         <div id="CharacterCount2" style="padding: 4px; float: left; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">Character Count:150:0</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="span2" data-bind=" visible: skill() != 'RES' ">Hours: <input class="span1" placeholder="Hours" data-bind="value: budget_hours"</input></div>
                     <div class="span2" data-bind=" visible: skill() != 'RES' ">Cost Rate: <input class="span1" placeholder="Cost Rate" data-bind="value: budget_cost_rate"</input></div>
                     <div class="span2" data-bind=" visible: skill() != 'RES' ">Charge Rate: <input class="span1" placeholder="Charge Rate" data-bind="value: budget_charge_rate "</input></div>

                     <div class="span2" data-bind="visible: skill() == 'RES'">Other Cost: <input class="span1" placeholder="Other Cost" data-bind="value: budget_other_cost"</input></div>
                     <div class="span2" data-bind="visible: skill() == 'RES'">Other Charge: <input class="span1" placeholder="Other Charge" data-bind="value: budget_other_charge"</input></div>
                 </div>
             </div>


        </div>
```

I would appreciate any help with this whatsoever! I am pulling my hair out!!

Many Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript part has to been like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#textAreaDescriptions").keyup(function() {
        var CharacterNo1 = $(this).val().length;
        $("#CharacterCount1").html ("Characters Used:50 : " + CharacterNo1);
    });

    $('#textAreaNote').keyup(function () {
        var CharacterNo2 = $(this).val().length;
        $('#CharacterCount2').html("Characters Used:150 : " + CharacterNo2);
    });
});
</script>
```

You have missed few basic bits like `$` inside `$(document).ready(function($)` and `#` before `textAreaDescriptions` in `$("#textAreaDescriptions").keyup(function()`

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have made the changes you suggested, but it still doesn't work?

Comment: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.length')
eachjquery.min.js:2:17955
global codecreate:171
feedback.js:2

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly then i would do like so:

```
 var keys = {};

  $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("textAreaDescriptions").keyup(function(event) {

                           keys[e.which] = true;


                            var CharacterNo1 = Object.keys(keys).length;
                            $("#CharacterCount1").html ("Characters Used:50 : " + CharacterNo1);
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I added this to my script tag, but it didn't work? i think the loop is stopping it from working?

Comment: what happens if you change from keyup to keydown?

Comment: still nothing - getting this though:

Comment: [Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.length')
 each (jquery.min.js, line 2)
 global code (create, line 171)